# PHP HelloWorld Error in Eclipse with XAMPP

Tags: php, eclipse, apache, xampp

I know that this question is probably going to be stupid, but I did not find a solution on the net.
I'm trying to create a simple HelloWorld program in PHP on Eclipse and with XAMPP. The code of the PHP class is

```
<?php
echo 'HelloWorld';
?>
```

but when I run it with the eclipse debugger I get this error:

> Warning: Use of undefined constant HelloWorld - assumed 'HelloWorld' 
>       in HelloWorld.php on line 1 HelloWorld

Comment: Does the php code run if you just run it from a browser?

Comment: @RiggsFolly not really. Firefox shows me a blank page. Chrome shows me a page with the code printed on it.

Comment: @Michele ... sounds as if Apache is not running? Put the code in a file named `test.php` (or some other name). This file should go into the `/xampp/htdocs` directory. Start Apache and then try this URL in the browser: `localhost/test.php`.  Replace the last portion of the URL if some other file name was used.